# What is wrong with my decryption function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption

```
import base64
import re

def encrypt(cleartext, key):
    to_return = bytearray(len(cleartext)) 
    for i in xrange(len(cleartext)):     
        to_return[i] = ord(cleartext[i]) ^ ord(key)
    return base64.encodestring(str(to_return))

def decrypt(ciphertxt,key):
    x = base64.decodestring(re.escape(ciphertxt))
    to_return = bytearray(len(x))
    for i in xrange(len(x)): 
        to_return[i] = ord(x[i]) ^ ord(key)

        while to_return[i]>127:
              to_return[i]-=127

    return to_return
```

When I encrypt bob then use my decrypt function it returns bob. However for longer things like paragraphs that when encrypted, the cipher text contains \ slashes it does not work. I do not get back ascii characters or base64 characters I get back weird chinese characters or square characters. Please any insight to point me in the right direction will help.

Comment: Why in the world are you using `re.escape()` here?  That's for preparing regular expression search patterns.  In the cases where it makes any changes to your string, it completely destroys the Base64 encoding from that point onwards.

Comment: BTW, this is _not_ a form of Caesar cipher.

Comment: You don't need to worry about strings with backslashes in them, unless they are literal strings that you've typed into your script.

Comment: The key could be anything from `chr(0)` to `chr(255)`.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question or attempt to vandalize the answers that people submit!

Comment: When you post material to Stack Overflow you have agreed to allow Stack Overflow to use that material, it's no longer your sole property. Please see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337003/4014959).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As jasonharper said, you're mangling your Base64 data by calling `re.escape` on it. Once you get rid of that, your code should be fine. I haven't tested it extensively, but it works correctly for me with multi-line text.

You should also get rid of this from your `decrypt` function:

```
while to_return[i]>127: 
    to_return[i]-=127
```

It won't do anything if the original cleartext is valid ASCII, but it will mess up the decoding if the cleartext does contain bytes > 127.

However, those functions could be a little more efficient.

FWIW, here's a version that works correctly on both Python 2 and Python 3. This code isn't as efficient as it could be on Python 3, due to the compromises made to deal with the changes in text and bytes handling in Python 3.

```
import base64

def encrypt(cleartext, key):
    buff = bytearray(cleartext.encode())
    key = ord(key)
    buff = bytearray(c ^ key for c in buff)
    return base64.b64encode(bytes(buff))

def decrypt(ciphertext, key):
    buff = bytearray(base64.b64decode(ciphertext))
    key = ord(key)
    buff = bytearray(c ^ key for c in buff)
    return buff.decode()

# Test

s = 'This is a test\nof XOR encryption'
key = b'\x53'
coded = encrypt(s, key)
print(coded)
plain = decrypt(coded, key)
print(plain)
```

**Python 3 output**

```
b'Bzs6IHM6IHMycyc2ICdZPDVzCxwBczY9MCEqIyc6PD0='
This is a test
of XOR encryption
```

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem. Can you give me an example string that produces weird output? If you want to give `encrypt` a literal string with _backslashes_  in it then you need to escape it correctly, but you don't use `re.escape` to do that.

Comment: @citruscake Why can't you post the text? Don't try to put it in a comment, put it in a code block at the end of your question. And you don't need to post the _exact_ text, just post something that reproduces the problem you're talking about.

Comment: You should just get rid of that `while to_return[i]>127:  to_return[i]-=127`. Sorry, I should've mentioned that earlier.

Comment: @citruscake You should have mentioned in your question that you're trying to find an unknown key. I assumed that you were just encoding & decoding stuff that you had control over. If you know that the message is supposed to be valid ASCII, then you can simply reject any results that contain chars >= chr(127).

Comment: BTW, do you _have_ to do this in Python 2?

Comment: @citruscake Have a loop that tries to decode with all possible keys. If you get a result that contains any chars >= chr(127) then just ignore that one and go onto the next key.

Comment: Coincidentally, a couple of days ago, I wrote Python 3 code for [this task](https://www.cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/3).

Comment: @citruscake I recommend using Python 3 because Python 2 does not make a clear distinction between bytes and text, so IMHO it's easier to get confused when doing stuff like this in Python 2.